# Select validation in magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, validation, form-validation, select

I am using magento2.1
If I am using class="validate-one-required-by-name and validate-select" it's not working.

```
<div class="control" style="margin:10px"> 
<select id="myselect" name="mySelect" class="validate-one-required-by-name" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Requested Type') ?>">
<option value="choose"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Please Select Options.') ?></option>
<option value="1">Test</option>
<option value="2">Test two</option>
<option value="3">Test Three</option>
<option value="4">Test Four</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Thank You

Comment: Have you got solution?

Answer (score 5):

You have to add null or empty value to select for validation work.
When you add like this

`<option value="choose"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Please Select Options.') ?></option>` it will not consider blank value so you should add like this

`<option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Please Select Options.') ?></option>`

Answer (score 4):

try with `class="required-entry"`.